# How to decrease the size of all texts in blogger (in posts, gadgets, etc)?

Tags: blogger

Is there a way to decrease the size of all texts (in posts, gadgets, etc) in my blogger blog? Now I have different text sizes for blog posts, gadgets and other texts, but I would like to decrease them all for about 5%. Is there a css code for that? In my html I found this

.post-body {font-size: 110%; line-height: 1.4; position: relative;}

When I change the % nothing happens to the texts. Only the space they take decreases or increases.

It would be ok even if I could change the text size only on posts. But all posts. I have 300+ posts in my website and I can't do it manually and change the size from Large to Normal. I mean I could, but it would take for ever.

Thank you